# How to store AES 256 Key in PKCS12 Keystore (.pks file or .p12) in C#

Tags: aes, .net, pkcs#12

I need to store AES 256 bit key in a keystore using C#. I tried to using [Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store](https://csharpdoc.hotexamples.com/class/Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs/Pkcs12Store) but not able to store AES Key.
I can do it in JAVA using the following code but not able to the same in C#.

```
try{
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keyStore.load(null, null);

        KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(256);
        Key key = keyGen.generateKey();
        for(byte b: key.getEncoded()) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
        System.out.println("");
        keyStore.setKeyEntry("secret", key, "password".toCharArray(), null);

        keyStore.store(new FileOutputStream("output.p12"), "password".toCharArray());

        try{
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream("output.p12"), "password".toCharArray());

            Key pvtKey = keyStore.getKey("secret", "password".toCharArray());
            //System.out.println(pvtKey.getEncoded().toString());
            for(byte b: pvtKey.getEncoded()) {
                System.out.print(b);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        } catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please help me out.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would also show us the C# code, and the actual error that you experience (an exception, compile error, something else..).

Comment: But judging by code on [github](https://github.com/kerryjiang/BouncyCastle.Crypto/blob/master/Crypto/pkcs/Pkcs12Store.cs) only private keys and certificates are supported .

Comment: Pkcs12Store.cs on official BouncyCastle github is actully [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/pkcs/Pkcs12Store.cs), but interface appears to be the same. You only have `SetCertificateEntry` and `SetKeyEntry`. If you want to be able to add any onther content you would have to make a new class based on this code and add the new functionality to it. It is not an easy task.